# How to generate random key for HMACSHA256 signature calculation

Tags: c#, random, cryptography, hmac

I need to calculate a signature of some strings and was planning on doing this like this:

```
using (HMACSHA256 hmacSha256 = new HMACSHA256( <randombytes>))
{
         Byte[] dataToHmac = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
         signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha256.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
}
```

I am going to store the key together with my user data, but i am not sure if the randombytes can just be random or how to generate them in c#.

What is the proper way to generate random keys?

Comment: I typically use a Random seeded with (int)DateTime.Now.Ticks and then use the Random.GetBytes method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @CodesInChaos can you elaborate? Last time I did it, I followed the general template provided by Microsoft here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545602(v=cs.70).aspx

Comment: 1) `System.Random` is (by design) not a secure PRNG 2) It has a 31 bit seed (2 billion different values), so any key generated by it can be brute-forced in a couple of minutes on modest hardware (a single AMD GPU). A naive C# brute-forcer would need 5 hours on a single CPU core.

Comment: @RonBeyer The linked article has one more fatal flaw: It uses a cheap hash to hash passwords, not a specialized (slow) password hash. See [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords) on security.se.

Comment: @RonBeyer That code makes absolutely no sense. It doesn't even *work*, throwing an exception. It has a `SaltValueSize`, but is hardcoded to use a 4 byte salt in other parts (much too short). In addition the authors produces random bytes and assumes these are valid UTF16, which is not guaranteed thanks to surrogate characters.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Agreed, but I won't even attempt to get that through the thick heads at M$. I haven't even heard a single peep from all my reports. At least the PHP guys in the end agreed to change the `mcrypt_encrypt` sample code (making all the comments below it off topic, but whatever).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your random bytes to be securely random, then you could use the [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx).